# How to determine if Vue is running via Vite or Webpack in development mode?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, vite

Vite and Webpack use different strategies to import modules.

I am writting a package that contains Vue files that recursively require components.
That logic is different in Vite and in Webpack.

Is there a way to determine if the code is being run in Vite or Webpack from within the component vue file?

I cannot seem to find a way to determine that.

I tried accessing `process.env` but it doesn't have that info there, i also tried `getCurrrentInstance()` and analyzed its object, but there is no info there either.

Is it possible to determine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Vite, `import.meta.env` will be defined. (`import.meta.env !== undefined`)

Using Webpack, `process.env` will be defined. (`process.env !== undefined`)

Comment: thank you! i also started checking for defined variables, but you are spot on about these particular variables for checking webpack vs vite.